# $\int_{0}^{2} (x-1)^3 dx + 2\int_{-1}^{2} (x-1)x dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$\int_{0}^{2} (x-1)^3 dx + 2\int_{-1}^2 (x-1)x dx$
$\int_{0}^{2} u^3 du + 2\int_{-1}^2 x^2 - x dx$
I get 4 + 3 = 7
But the answer is 3. Where am i wrong? Any hints anyone?

Comment: When you did the u substitution you didn't change the bounds of integration.

$$\int_{0}^{2}(x-1)^{3}dx=\int_{-1}^{1}u^{3}du=0$$

 If $u=x-1$ then as $x$ travels from $0$ to $-2$ then $u$ travels from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: Oh right. I will try again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$I=(\frac{(x-1)^4}{4})|_{0}^{2}+(2\frac{x^3}{3}-x^2)|_{-1}^{2}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}+[(2\frac{8}{3}-4)-(2\frac{-1}{3}-1)]=\frac{4}{3}+\frac{5}{3}=3$$